# Can "a->b=1;c=a" be reordered?

Tags: c, memory

It seems that [`a=1;b=a;`](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch09lev1sec10) can not be reordered, because there is an obvious dependency.

Not sure about `a->b=1; c=a`.

Comment: Do you know what `a->b` is?  It doesn't seem like you can assign `b=a` in that case.

Comment: Isn't `a=1;b=a;` the same as `b=1;a=1;` ?

Comment: Yes: `b = a; a->b = 1;` produces the same result as `a->b = 1; b = a;`.  Note that the `b` to the right of the `->` arrow is unrelated to the `b` variable.

Comment: In most (maybe all) cases, `a=1;b=a;` can certainly be reordered.

Comment: Looks like this question has exploited something like [Equivocation fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation) in several commenters at once.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Surely not. `b=a; a=1;` is something completely different.

Comment: @glglgl: I mean that it can be reordered by setting `b=1` before setting `a=1`.

Answer (score 2):

`a->b = 1` means `a` is a pointer to some struct which has a field named `b`, so either `b=a` generates a compiler error about `b` not being defined, or `b` is defined as a pointer to struct as well, so they are completely unrelated.

```
struct somestr
{
  int b;
};
...
...
struct somestr *a;
...
...
a->b = 1; /* OK */
b = a;  /* symbol "b" not found */
...
...
...
struct somestr *a, *b;
...
...
a->b = 1; /* OK */
b = a;    /* OK too */
```

Comment: Meaning the last two lines can be reordered, to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
a->b=1; c=a;
```

as you write it now, provided that `a` and `c` are pointers to the same struct type, has the meaning that the `b` field of a struct pointed to by `a` is set to 1.

Afterwards, you let the pointer `c` point to the same structure.

These operations can clearly interchanged, as they don't affect each other. Both work the same way, no matter if the other was executed or not.